# How can I select an appropriate lag input for time series which can be applied for neural networks?

Tags: time-series, neural-networks, feature-selection, lags

Because of nature of the autocorrelation in a time series, the number of input nodes or lagged observations used in the neural networks is often important factor.

How can I select an appropriate lagged observation for a specific dataset?